# Why does my GPS service on an Android device decline after some time?

Tags: gps, gps-tracking

On my Android 11 phone I notice a certain decline of the GPS reception when used with the app "Caynax Sport Tracker". After a reboot of the device (realme 8 pro) the GPS tracking works just fine. But after a week or so there are random drops in the GPS reception (5-30 seconds). The application then tells me that there is no GPS reception.

After a reboot of the Android device the GPS reception works fine again. For about a week.

What could be the cause of this issue, and why can it only be solved by restarting the Android device?

Can it be:

- a bad quality android (creating random errors after a week of operation...?)
- a bad quality GPS software (maybe an internal counter creating random errors ..?)
- a bad quality GPS device (maybe some charge building up which only can be discharged by rebooting the device?)
- a bad quality application (...?)

What is the likely cause of this annoyance, and why can it be solved only by a reboot?

Comment: The common was GPS data flows is GPS chip -> GPS daemon -> Android location services -> app. If a reboot fixes the problem it could be one any component before the app.

Comment: @Robert: But what could be the possible cause of the problem? What could be the case in the GPS chip? In the GPS daemon? In the Android location service? Why does it always deteriorate  after some time?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think it is possible to answer your questions without the possibility to directly access the device. I would check other forums that are dedicated for your device only (e.g. there should be one on XDA forums) if this problem is known for your device model. Otherwise it may be just a glitch or a hardware defect.